# Easiest way to reuse small section of code

Tags: java, methods, formatting

I have a section of code like this:

```
            while (scanFile.hasNextLine()) 
            {
                String currentLine = scanFile.nextLine();
                if (currentLine.isEmpty())
                {
                    System.out.println();
                    continue;
                }
                String[] allWordsInCurrentLine = currentLine.split(" ");
```

I then have three separate methods I want to use to manipulate the file being scanned.

The first method scans each line of the code individually and prints out some form of output (pigLatin) line by line (so one line of output is given for each iteration of the "while" loop.
The second method scan all the text first and stores various information in different arrays and variables. The user can then search this information (so the entire "while" loop must be satisfied before any output can be given).
I then have a third method which does something similar to the first one.

I am trying to find the most efficient way to reuse this section of code. Originally, I tried just doing method calls underneath the bottom line of the code above and have a for loop at the top of it, so if a==0, call first method, then second time through while loop, a will be incremented and second method will be called and so on, like this:

```
for(String currentWordInCurrentLine : allWordsInCurrentLine)
{
    if (i==0)
        pigLatin(currentWordInCurrentLine);         // Part 1
    if (i==1)
        searchForWord(currentWordInCurrentLine, currentLine);   // Part 2
    if (i==2)
        brailleTranslator();
}
```

There are a few issues with this, not the least the fact it looks awful. Someone advised me to try interfaces, but they are a bit above my station (am only a few weeks into my course). Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Edit: The pigLatin method call works fine using the above (albeit horrible looking) way. However, I can't call the next method like that, as it needs to run through the whole 'while' loop before it can operate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would wrap the functionality you want with your three different processes in their own custom callable-like class, and then pass them to the code above.  In this case the shared code would look something like this:

```
public class FileHandlerManager {

    public static void processFile(File file, List<FileHandler> handlers) {

        // ... Setup your scanFile from your file... leaving this out.

        while (scanFile.hasNextLine()) {

            String currentLine = scanFile.nextLine();

            String[] allWordsInCurrentLine = currentLine.split(" ");

            for (FileHandler handler : handlers) {
                handler.handle(allWordsInCurrentLine);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can share the functionality of that while loop across `FileHandler`.  What is a `FileHandler`?  I would define it very simply, like this:

```
public interface FileHandler {
    public void handle(String[] allWordsInCurrentLine);
}
```

Your first one might look like this:

```
public class PigLatinFileHandler implements FileHandler {
    public void handle(String[] allWordsInCurrentLine) {
        // Do your piglatin code.
    }
}
```

And finally, to run it, you would do something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    IndexingFileHandler indexHandler = new IndexingFileHandler();

    List<FileHandler> handlers = new LinkedList<FileHandler>();
    handlers.add(new PigLatinFileHandler());
    handlers.add(indexHandler);
    handlers.add(new SimilarToPigLatinFileHandler());

    FileHandlerManager.processFile(file, handlers);

    // Note now you have a reference to indexHandler; so if you wanted to save
    // any state while processing the words you can, and use it here.
}
```

**EDIT**

I just want to point out that there is an "easier", less object-oriented way; you could have a method take a file and return a String[][], which is a two-dimensional array of file lines by words in those lines.  Then you can pass around that array to your handlers.

However the downside with this approach is that it breaks on large files (you have to load the whole thing into memory at once) and you don't get any output until the entire file has been read.  A (maybe non-obvious) advantage of my answer is that you "stream" the file; you process a line with all of the handlers, and then throw out the line, allowing java to reuse that memory.  This code would let you handle a 10 GB file while only using java memory equal to the length of the longest line in that file (plus any state that your IndexHandler is saving).

Comment: I'll give it a go - at first glance, looks awesome. You've explained it really well, thanks.

Comment: Can I ask - do I need to create the IndexingFileHandler and FileHandlerManager objects? I get errors in Java saying they cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: @AndrewMartin Yes, I provided basic class definitions for them; they should be very lightweight.  If you are worried about class file explosion and making the code harder to follow, you could also make them inner classes inside FileHandlerManager: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html or change `FileHandlerManager` to `FileHandler` and have the processFile remain its only static method.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to put your logic into a base class like this:

```
public class Base {
  public void run() {
    while(...) {
      consume(word);
    }
  }
  protected void consume(string word){
  }
}
```

Then you can create for each job a class:

```
public PigLatin extends Base {
  protected void consume(string word) {
    // do piggy stuff..
  }
}
```

You can run everything like that:

```
...
Base l1 = new PigLatin();
l1.run();

Base l2 = new WordSearch();
l2.run();
...
```

In your case it doesn't look reasonable to do this, it probably complicates your code. But I think it's a good exercise.

The disadvantage of this solution is that you have to iterate through your file every time you call `run()`. You usually do this if you want to separate different runs. If you're sure those runs don't interfere with each other, then Cory Kendall's solution is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you, will review both yours and his answers and see which one fits best!